# Broadcasting a Series to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Series like:

```
A    2
B    3
C    4
```

And a DataFrame like:

```
    A   B   C
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
```

I want to assign the series to all rows in the dataframe. This is the expected output:

```
    A   B   C
0   2   3   4
1   2   3   4
2   2   3   4
```

Of cause I can do

```
for col in ser.index:
    df[col] = ser[col]
```

but what is a more efficient way?

Answer (score 4):

Using `pandas.DataFrame.div` and `mul`:

```
df.div(df).mul(s)
```

Or much faster using `numpy.tile` (iff `df.columns == s.index`):

```
pd.DataFrame(np.tile(s, (len(df), 1)), columns=df.columns)
```

Output:

```
     A    B    C
0  2.0  3.0  4.0
1  2.0  3.0  4.0
2  2.0  3.0  4.0
```

Comment: That's a clever answer!!

Answer (score 2):

#### `assign`

With no checks, just assign a column for anything found in `s` across all rows:

```
df.assign(**s)
#   A  B  C
#0  2  3  4
#1  2  3  4
#2  2  3  4
```

---

Alternatively just create the DataFrame from `s`, and concat back only the columns you didn't update:

```
pd.concat([df[df.columns.difference(s.index)],
           pd.DataFrame(s.to_dict(), index=df.index)],
          axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
df = df.replace(df, ser)
```

or

```py
df = df.apply(lambda x : ser, axis=1)
```

**Example**:
Use [pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas-dataframe-apply) with `lambda function` and `axis = 1`

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,4,7],'B':[2,5,8],'C':[3,6,9]})
>>> ser = pd.Series({'A':2,'B':3,'C':4})
```

```
>>> df = df.apply(lambda x : ser, axis=1)
```

```
>>> df
   A  B  C
0  2  3  4
1  2  3  4
2  2  3  4
```

Second Solution:

```
>>> df = df.replace(df, ser)
>>> df
   A  B  C
0  2  3  4
1  2  3  4
2  2  3  4
```

Answer (score 0):

**Very fast** even for large df's, assuming your df columns are in the same order as your series index, is `numpy` broadcasting:

`df.loc[:,:] = ser.to_numpy()[None, :]`

The `None` tells it to broadcast (copy-fill) to match what it's working with.

Answer (score -1):

A solution without a loop, not sure if it's really more efficient though

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
DF = pd.DataFrame({
                   'A':[1,4,7],
                   'B': [2,5,8],
                   'C': [3,6,9]})
ser = pd.Series([2,3,4], index =['A','B','C'])
```

First converting the Pandas series to dictionary

```
dict=ser.to_dict()
```

Then put null values everywhere in dataframe:

```
DF.loc[:,:] = np.NaN
```

And finally use `fillna` method with `dict` indicating which value to put in each column

```
DF.fillna(dict)
```